# How to label colnames of a dataframe directly with a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, label

I have a dataframe with 300 columns. I would like to label the columns with a vector (consisting of 300 entries).
I try to use the labelled package. But I don't want to assign each variable to a label one by one -> `id= "Identity"`, `age = "Age"`....etc.
I would like to assign the label names from a vector directly to the columns -> `c("Identity", "Age", ...`

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)

#dataframe
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 300, nrow = 2))
#vector of labels for columns
label_colname <- sprintf("label_colname[%d]",seq(1:300))

df %>% set_variable_labels(label = label_colname)
```

> `error in set_variable_labels(., label = label_colname) :  some variables not found in .data`

Comment: did you try `colnames(df)<-label_colname`

Comment: `names(df) <- c('vector', 'of', 'new', 'names')`?

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions are changing the variable names. My intention is to label short variable names like "dos" with " Date of Surgery" to receive meaningful names for tables. The variable name is short without extra symbols. The labels are more complicated with brackets, extra space etc. The label names are not appropriate for variable names.

Comment: Ah, afaik there's not a well-supported way to do that. You could add it as attributes, but attributes get dropped without warning very easily, and you'd have to pull the label back out when you want it. `vctrs` enables some things like this, but you'd have to build it yourself and it's overkill. The usual workflow is to either change names to readable ones at the last minute or change them directly on the table/plot/whatever. Storing them in a lookup table is handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since label is just stored as an attribute you can also do this directly in base R:

```
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  attr(df[[i]], "label") <- label_colname[i]
}
```

[image]

Data (burrowed from TarJae)

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))
label_colname <- sprintf("label_colname[%d]",seq(1:30))
```

Answer (score 0):

I now found the solution with the sjlabelled package:

```
library(sjlabelled)

df <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 30, nrow = 2))
label_colname <- sprintf("label_colname[%d]",seq(1:30))

df <- set_label(df, label = label_colname) # set_label from sjlabelled package
```

[image]